# Keeping images in sync with web server in iOS with regards to foto stream

Tags: ios, ios11, phasset

Simple scenario: I like to synchronize images on my server with an iOS app. The app regularly gets a list of image resources and downloads these to the iOS photo album / creates PHAssets. The app stores both the PHAssets fresh localIdentifier and the resource url with core data. It will not download these images again. Let's say this is happening on my iPhone and on my iPad. Let's say both devices ran these synchronisation jobs and are 100% in sync with my webserver.
And here is the catch: the iOS foto stream will produce a copy of each downloaded image on the respective other device - once it had enough time to do its own syncing. I will end up with duplicates on both devices.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it should be PHAsset's property "originalFilename". If I set this to a globally unique identifier, I can recognize files, which have already been downloaded to this device.